# Web API Performance counters

Tags: asp.net-web-api

In WCF I used performance counters in windows performance monitor a lot to monitor my services.
Now I have new services developed in WebApi and I can't see performance counters for it. I really need the InCall counter and few other ones.
All the solutions I found online involve coding (in the service itself). That's not good because I don't have the code for all the services I want to monitor.